# Canada NOC code for Backend /Java developer

Tags: canada, express-entry

I have seen this link -
[NOC 2173 vs 2174](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/13831/noc-code-for-software-developer-2173-or-2174?newreg=32b69b8c4a2248dc8f2edc78e29b309c)  but still having some doubts.

I am a java developer and my day to day work involve writing code, testing it, modifying existing code as per requirements. I have also worked on writing server and applications from scratch. Whatever issues or bugs we find before or after release, upon testing, I myself fix some of them and communicate it to a wider team.
I also prepare reports from JIRA to track the work status in order to ensure continuous delivery and maintenance of the software. I have worked a bit on front-end in Angular 5+ too.
I am a scrum master and coaching team of 9 people as a scrum coach. Furthermore, I manage software releases in which I coordinate with multiple teams in my function across the globe.
To conclude, my major time is invested in coding only and I am only 3.5 years experienced so not at a managerial position.

Please guide in selecting NOC 2173 vs 2174.
I also wanted to know let's say I get PR by NOC 2174 then after landing can I just apply to jobs related to NOC 2174 only or can apply for 2173 too?

Answer (score 0):

You should go ahead with 2173 which is Software engineers and designers since the majority of your time is spent on coding only. You can omit the parts about scrum master and other managerial things in your resume and experience letter or just mention them, rather than giving them any weight. This is not uncommon in software industry.

After getting the PR, you can apply for any jobs. It won't matter what NOC code you got the PR for. You can work in retail, deliver mails, become a manager- if you get my drift.

Comment: Isnt 2174 more associated with coding?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter if both categories can be justified in good faith. The only times it matters is when one code is of a higher level or is targeted by a particular immigration program.

> I also wanted to know let's say I get PR by NOC 2174 then after landing can I just apply to jobs related to NOC 2174 only or can apply for 2173 too?

No such restrictions exist. Once you obtain the permanent resident status, you are free to study, work, retire or otherwise live in Canada, with the same rights and responsibilities as Canadian citizens, except with respect to elections, public offices and a very limited number of situations (e.g. security clearances).

The same applies even if you obtained points due to a LMIA job offer. You do not have a legal obligation to work for that employer (but there are moral considerations and contractual terms can still apply).