# Roles and responsibilities for a Java Backend developer

Tags: canada, express-entry

My company has given me an experience letter and below are the roles and responsibilities listed in it. Please guide me in choosing 2173 vs 2174 as NOC code. There's still some room for changes so welcoming suggestions.

•   Work on micro-services based Java server application using Java 8, Spring, Hibernate from scratch.

•   Write, modify and test software code by Junit5 and Mockito unit tests. Integrate existing systems to newly developed servers and applications and ensuring that it doesn’t break existing workflows and systems.

•   Work on existing servers, applications and computer programs by modifying the code as per the requirements from our business and users.

•   Identify, communicate and fix technical bugs or problems found before or after the software release by testing code and associated functionality and communicating solutions to the wider team

•   Gather business/technical requirements and document them in Confluence wiki and individual JIRA tickets and assign it to the team.

•   Researched and evaluated the performance of various third party software for incorporating the plugin architecture in the project.

•   Worked as a release manager and coordinated across teams to manage the release of the software by creating release packets and deployment wikis.

•   Worked as a scrum master and lead a team of computer programmers as a scrum coach by organizing scrum meetings.

•   Create reports, burn down charts and other documentation from JIRA to track the status and operation of software and to ensure continuous delivery and maintenance.

Comment: Similar question from OP here https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/20850/canada-noc-code-for-backend-java-developer

Comment: @DipenShah I wanted to know whether the above list qualifies for 2174 or not ?

Comment: I believe my original answer still stands. Compare the main duties section in the links in my previous answer and choose one that fits best.

Comment: @DipenShah - I have got a list of responsibilities from my company, I'll edit the question with these and then you please let me know whether it's 2174 or 2173.